# Getting errors In My New Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eight, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) mWebView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_eight_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
}
```

Problems:

```
Error:(29, 9) error: unreachable statement
Error:(33, 5) error: missing return statement
```

problem is showing in 5th line from last

Comment: Your return in onCreateView should be at the end of your method, all the statements under are unreachable hence the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have dead code, you are returning at the top of your function:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eight, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView)     mWebView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_eight_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
}
```

Replace with

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eight, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView)     view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_eight_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked Well Thanks A lLot

Answer (score 0):

the return line need to be to the end of the method.

in this case, this line.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eight, container, false);
```